# JTextPane: KeyBindings are not working on StyledEditorKit

Tags: java, swing, jtextpane, key-bindings, keyevent

Please have a look at the following code

```
import java.awt.Color;    
import java.awt.Dimension;    
import java.awt.FlowLayout;    
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;    
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;    
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.util.ArrayList;    
import java.util.List;    
import java.util.logging.Level;    
import java.util.logging.Logger;    
import javax.swing.*;    
import javax.swing.text.*;    

    public class Form1 extends JFrame      
    {      
        private JTextPane textPane;      
        private JPanel south;    
        private JScrollPane scroll;      

        private String  content;      
        public String documentType;                


        private DefaultStyledDocument document;          
        int start, end, offset1,length1;         
        private JButton button;             
        JFrame frame;    


        public Form1()      
        {      

            //Declaring the instance variables      
            textPane = new JTextPane();      
            textPane.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(100,100));      

            button = new JButton("Bold");      
            button.addActionListener(new StyledEditorKit.BoldAction());     
             button.getInputMap().put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_B,KeyEvent.CTRL_MASK),"key");
        button.getActionMap().put("key", new StyledEditorKit.BoldAction());

            document = (DefaultStyledDocument) textPane.getDocument();        




            //Creating the main window     
            south = new JPanel();      
            south.setLayout(new FlowLayout());      
            south.add(button);                          
            scroll = new JScrollPane(textPane);      

            getContentPane().add(scroll,"Center");      
            getContentPane().add(south,"South");                  

            setSize(800,600);    
            validate();    
            setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);                          
        }     


        private class Action extends AbstractAction    
        {      
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae)      
            {              
                new StyledEditorKit.BoldAction();
            }
        }      

       public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {       
            SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable()       
            {        
              @Override        
              public void run() {        
               Form1 f = new Form1();  
               f.setVisible(true);
              }        
            });        
          }       
    }
```

In here, user can enter any text, and when he select a text and click on "Bold" button, the text will be bold. However, I need to do it using CTRL+B also. As you can see, my attempt is not giving any response to that key event. I even tried adding it to a seperate class which extends AbstractAction, but still no good. How can I implement the CTRL+B here? Please help...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When key bindings don't work for me, the first place I look is the InputMap -- am I sure that I'm using the right one?  Well, are you sure? The default one uses `JComponent.WHEN_FOCUSED` and thus only works if your component has the focus.

If you want it to work at other times, say when the bound component is visible and in a focused window but doesn't necessarily have the focus itself, perhaps you should try different condition parameters. Try using `JComponent.WHEN_IN_FOCUSED_WINDOW` to start with.

i.e.,

```
InputMap inputMap = myComponent.getInputMap(JComponent.WHEN_IN_FOCUSED_WINDOW);
```