# Setting the same key shortcuts for buttons under different tabs

Tags: java, swing, jbutton, key-bindings, keylistener

I have a frame which is multi tabbed and I have to set shortcuts to certain buttons under different tabs, but they have to use the same key.
For example:

> Under tab1, I have a "Do that" button which should react to F1 key,
>   but if I were to switch to tab2, I should have a "Do this" button
>   which should also react to F1 button but the action on tab1 shouldn't
>   be fired.

I have tried adding `keylistener` to tabs/keys/panels but still, if I were to press F1 key, it's the first action that is fired.

But I think the reason is that I use a switch, which controls the key events, such as `case KeyEvent.VK_F1:mybutton1.doclick();`

So how do I separate actions to react separately under different tabs? Is there a way to get the focused tab for example or something else?

Regards.

Edit:some code for Swing action:

```
    private class SwingAction extends AbstractAction {
    public SwingAction() {
        putValue(NAME, "mybutton");
        putValue(SHORT_DESCRIPTION, "Some short description");
    }
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        mybutton.getInputMap().put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke("F1"),"pressed");
        mybutton.getActionMap().put("pressed",mybutton.doClick());

    }
}
```

i get :

> The method put(Object, Action) in the type ActionMap is not applicable
>   for the arguments (String, void)
>   error, ( sorry a Java/Swing newbie here)

Answer (score 4):

use

- [Swing Action](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/action.html) for [JButton](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/button.html#abstractbutton), you can to set the same [JBUtton#setAction()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/AbstractButton.html#setAction%28javax.swing.Action%29) for any JCOmponents that implements `Swing Action`
- [KeyBindings](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html) (for `F1`) with output to the `Swing Action`, inside `Action` you have to call [JButton#doClick()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/AbstractButton.html#doClick%28%29)
- don't use [KeyListener](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/keylistener.html) for [Swing JComponents](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/index.html), ever

Comment: cheers tried '   mybutton.getInputMap().put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke("F1"),"pressed");
   mybutton.getActionMap().put("pressed",mybutton.doClick());'  couldnt get it to work.. :/

Comment: no idea without posting an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/), works for me, [rest is described here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10674489/714968), your [SSCCE could be based on](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10591773/714968) , @Hovercraft Full Of Eels, Pete thank you for two great posts here :-)

Comment: excelent described issue about [JButton and KeyBindings](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10712202/714968)  by @trashgod

Answer (score 3):

Binding a `KeyStroke` to a button's `doClick()` has the advantage of visual and auditory feedback; but, as you've observed, `doClick()` is not an `Action`. Instead, create an `Action` that invokes a given button's `doClick()` method, and bind it to the desired `KeyStroke`, as shown in this [example](https://sites.google.com/site/drjohnbmatthews/keypad-panel).